# In Angularjs, need to include dropdown in one of header cell of ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am using ag-grid and could not find documentation related to Individual header cell template feature. In the example [header rendering](http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-header-rendering/index.php), the rendering appears to all headers, instead I want to modify the appearance of one or two header cells only instead of all. Foe example, for header 'age' I want to have one drop down below to 'age' with in the header cell, how can I achieve it? Can any one point me to some sample code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the headerCellRenderer onto the colDef in addition to the gridOptions. If on the colDef, then it's only used for that column.